# How to get xpath to filtered elements in Symfony DomCrawler?

Tags: symfony

I would like to get xpath of all h2 headers on page. I am using Symfony DomCrawler to accomplish it, with which I've created following workaround

```
$h2s = $crawler->filter('h2');
$h2s->each(function($header)
{
            $path = [];

            foreach($header->parents() as $parent)
            {
                $path[] = $parent->tagName;
            }

            $path = '//' . join("/", array_reverse($path));
});
```

Anyway, it is not perfect. Generated xpath aren't unique. Some div have got necessary classes, ids etc. **How can I generate xpath to each dom element or some other unique attribute like hash?**